# Show a dynamic chart in MVC3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, charts

I have a situation where in I need to show a chart in MVC3 view.
Till now I have done the following
in my controller

```
public ActionResult MyChart()
        {
            var bytes = new Chart(width: 400, height: 200)
                .AddSeries(
                    chartType: "bar",
                    xValue: new[] {"Math", "English", "Computer", "Urdu"},
                    yValues: new[] {"60", "70", "68", "88"})
                .GetBytes("png");
            return File(bytes, "image/png");
        }
```

in my Jquery file

```
function getChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url: ('/Home/MyChart'),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.length);
            $('#BottomGrid').html(result);
        },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
    }
```

and in my view I am simply calling the getChart() method. 
my view is an .aspx view and bottomgrid is a div on the view where I need to show the chart.

Running the above code in IE gives me a png sign and in firefox it shows me special characters.

Any Idea where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your "getChart()" function :

```
 success: function (result) {
        alert(result.length);
        $('#BottomGrid').append('<img id="myChart" />');
        $('#myChart').attr("src", "/Home/MyChart")
    }
```

but i don't think it's an ideal solution,because it request the image twice , the first one when you do ajax (it needs a way to render the returned text as image),the second one when the browser parse "img" tag.

Comment: Actully you can just write these two statments :
        $('#BottomGrid').append('<img id="myChart" />');
        $('#myChart').attr("src", "/Home/MyChart");

instead of doing ajax call. :)